# How to add a type of Void to a tuple?

Tags: swift, tuples

I have some trouble with declaring the type Void for a tuple collection. 
I get an error of: `Nil is not compatible with expected element type 'Void '`

```
var messages: [(person: String, type: String, text: String, action: Void, isSender: Bool)]? = [
    (person: "Buddy", type: "instruction", text: "Wat vervelend van uw schade. De volgende vragen moeten direct op locatie ingevuld worden", action: nil,  isSender: false),
    (person: "User", type: "question", text: "Wat is uw locatie en tijd?", action: askPermissionForGPS(), isSender: true)
]
```

I already tried to place `lazy` before the dictionary collection and the different ways to declare the type `Void`, `Void -> ()`, `() -> Void`, but with no result.

What I want is that the tuple can have an function as argument or nil.

Comment: instead of Void try to use: () -> Void

Comment: Already tried. Same result

Comment: You can even use `(() -> Void)?` if you allow `nil`

Comment: try ( () -> Void )?.   this will make the parameter optional allowing a nil value to be passed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `nil` you have to declare the `action` parameter as optional

```
var messages: [(person: String, type: String, text: String, action: Void?, isSender: Bool)]? = [ ...
```

But I recommend to declare the `action` parameter as closure

```
var messages: [(person: String, type: String, text: String, action: (()->Void)?, isSender: Bool)]? = [ ...
```

then you can pass just the function name

```
 (person: "User", 
    type: "question", 
    text: "Wat is uw locatie en tijd?", 
  action: askPermissionForGPS, 
isSender: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Void` is a `typealias` for a 0 element tuple. I assume you would like to have action type to be closure eg. `() -> ()`. Then if it can be `nil` - make it optional: `(() ->())?`